# Stop exporting buttons and checkbox columns

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a dataTable where two columns are checkbox and button, respectively. The checkbox column is blank column but the button appears "org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButton @ 13c643". How can I not print these columns to export the dataTable to excel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

by this property exportable="false" column can be ignored

from export in p:dataExporter ..

```
<p:column exportable="false" >
    <p:commandButton 

    </p:commandButton>
</p:column>
```